# Adding element to ArrayList by index denied by Collection interface

Tags: java, arraylist, calendar, compareto

I am sorting an ArrayList of objects that include Calendar objects. I wish to sort the ArrayList ascending or descending based on the parameter used when the method for sorting is called.

```
@Override
public Collection<TwitterMessage> sortByTime(boolean newestFirst) {
    Collection<TwitterMessage> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
        TwitterMessage tweet1 = tweets.get(i);
        TwitterMessage tweet2 = tweets.get(i+1);
        if(newestFirst = true) {
            if(tweet1.dato().compareTo(tweet2.dato()) >= 0) {
                results.add(0, tweet1);
            }
        }
        else {
            if(tweet1.dato().compareTo(tweet2.dato()) <= 0) {
                results.add(0, tweet1);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

I think this method is correct. The problem is that the returntype is specified in the Interface to be based on the Collection interface. I get a compilaton error on the

```
results.add(0, tweet1);
```

line because the Collection interface only allows results.add(object), and not results.add(int, object) as an ArrayList does. Is there a way I could add the object to an index, even though this is not in the Collection interface?

Comment: Also `if(newestFirst = true)`, is certainly not what you are looking for. It should be `if(newestFirst == true)`, or even better `if(newestFirst)`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply declare your variable as a List:

```
List<TwitterMessage> results = new ArrayList<>();
```

To sort a list, you should use `Collections.sort()`, passing a custom comparator as argument.

Comment: Thank you. Why not do it the way I've implemented it? I'm keen to learn reasons behind the best practice.

Comment: Because the way you've implemented it, it doesn't compile. To be able to call a method specific to the List type, your variable has to be declared as List (or any of its subclasses), otherwise, the compiler can't know that the type of the collection is List.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask why I should use Collections.sort(). I declared the results variable as an ArrayList and now it compiles.

Comment: Because Collections.sort() does what you want to do: sorting a list. Your method doesn't sort a list. Test it.

Comment: Why do the sorting job yourself when you can use a built-in method that does it for you? ;)